# How to handle File download dialog/popup in IE browser USING SELENIUM and C#

Tags: file, internet-explorer, selenium, download

I have page which downloads a file which shows a dialog on the bottom with OPEN SAVE CANCEL options, how can I click those options ? I am using IE browser, I saw some solutions using third party AutoIt, Robot class, but I am looking with Selenium and C# only. Attached is the image of what I am talking.. Any idea how can we do this ?[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @GabrielBourgault No I couldn't find. From my understanding I found that it's not in reach to verify

Comment: Thanks.. too bad selenium can't handle this

Comment: here is solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240146/selenium-download-file-in-internet-explorer-to-specified-folder-without-direct/48240157#48240157

Comment: One way to handle -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/66791484/7666582

Answer (score 1):

```
 AutoItX3 autoit = new AutoItX3();
                autoit.WinActivate("Save");            
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                autoit.Send("{F6}");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                autoit.Send("{TAB}");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                autoit.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;    
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SampleTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Download()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Users\hamit\Desktop\Selenium\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.48.0");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.spotify.com/se/download/windows/");

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("@{TAB}"); Thread.Sleep(100);
        SendKeys.SendWait("@{TAB}"); Thread.Sleep(100);
        SendKeys.SendWait("@{DOWN}"); Thread.Sleep(100);
        SendKeys.SendWait("@{DOWN}"); Thread.Sleep(100);
        SendKeys.SendWait("@{Enter}");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't wotk for my case.
This case doesn't select the pop up to Save the file or Open.Because you have the meassage in a pop-up. Or you just disable the pop-up (http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/) and the download done or is impossible.

This is a good article to read.
http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/07/25/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt.html

Answer (score 0):

like an option - try get all exist buttons and then filter by inner text

```
var posibleButtons = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("button")).Where(el => el.Text.Contains("Open"));
posibleButtons.Where(// try use some other filters, maybe by styles or ets...
```

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 for security reasons do not allow us to skip that part. Since this is not the DOM, you cannot handle it with selenium..

AutoIT or similar tools are the only option, which makes the test less reliable..

instead, we added API calls to get the documents instead of actually downloading them.

Answer (score 0):

Tried in Java, file was downloaded.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "j"));
Thread.sleep(2000);
Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Explaination:

1 First click on the button / link to download the file.this pop up will be seen enter image description here
[image]
2. Click "Ctrl+j" this will open the "View Downloads pop up".
3.Then click enter , since the focus will be on the recent file, it
will be downloaded